# Выборка по дате + по общему признаку

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть таблица с 2 полями - число и дата.
Я хочу выполнить запрос "выбери мне все записи из таблицы, у которых дата находится в указанном диапазоне", но расширить его таким образом, чтобы записи с одинаковым признаком, даже если они не входят в диапазон по дате, попали в итоговый результат, если хотя бы 1 дата с данным признаком попала в диапазон. наглядный пример:

```
field1 field2
1      01.01.2018
1      31.12.2017
2      31.12.2017
```

Условие попадания в итоговую выборку - field2 = 31.12.2017 + записи с признаком field1, которому хотя бы 1 раз соответствует необходимая дата. Т.е. в итоге мне должны вернуть все 3 записи.

Благодарю заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
Select field1, field2
from table
where field2='20171231' or field1 in (select distinct field1 from table
where field2='20171231')
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо!